# Regex cannot prevent a match of suffix name made up using I,V,X and SR/JR

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to prevent the inclusion of suffix name, for example, `JR`/`SR`, or other suffix made up of using `I,V,X` using regular expression way. To accomplish this I have implemented the following regex

```
((^((?!((\b((I+))\b)|(\b(V+)\b)|(\b(X+)\b)|\b(IV)\b|(\b(V?I){1,2}\b)|(\b(IX)\b)|(\bX[I|IX]{1,2}\b)|(\bX|X+[V|VI]{1,2}\b)|(\b(JR)\b)|(\b(SR)\b))).)*$))
```

Using this I am able to prevent various possible combination eg.,
'Last Name I',
'Last Name II',
'Last Name IJR',
'Last Name SRX' etc.

However, there are still couple of combinations remaining, which this regex can match. eg., 'Last Name IXV' or 'Last Name VXI'

These two I am not able to debug. Please suggest me in which part of this regex I can make changes to satisfy the requirement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern: `.+\b(?:(?>[JS]R)|X|I|J|V)+$`

Explanation:

`.+` - match one or more of any characters

`\b` - word boudnary

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`(?>...)` - atomic group

`[JS]R` - match whether `S` or `J` followed by `R`

`|` - alternation: match what is on the left OR what's on the right

`+` - quantifier: match one or more times preceeding pattern

`$` - match end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksIxPl/2)

Comment: Turczyn Thanks for the tip. However, it doesn't prevent capturing of suffix name. I am trying to accomplish the following: if there is a suffix name I would like to return a "no match" result. Anyway, I am a bit curious to know more about, that, how can I translate a query into regex or thought process. Hope this question won't bother you! Thank you!

Comment: @NikhilG If this answer has helpedyou you should accpet it (green check nark on the left) and optionally upvote it

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this I have worked on the above regex a little bit more. And here is the final result that can successfully match up with the "roman numeral" upto thirty constituted I, V, and X.

---

`"(\b(?!(IIX|IIV|IVV|IXX|IXI))I[IVX]{0,3}\b|\b(V|X)\b|\bV[I]{1,2}\b|\b((?!XVV|XVX)X([IXV]{1,2}))\b|\b[S|J]R\b)|^$"`

---

**What I have done here is:**

- I have taken those input into consideration which are standalone,
  that is: `SR` or `XXV`  I have observed the incorrect pattern and
  have restricted them to match as a positive result.

  - Separate input has been ensured using `\b` the word boundary.

> *Word-boundary:* It suggests that starting of a word, that means in
>   simple words it says "yes there is a word" or "no it is not."

- it has done in the following way- 
  using negative lookahead `(?!(IIX|IIV|IVV|IXX|IXI))`

**How I have arrived on this solution is given as follows:**

- I have observed closely all the pattern first, that from I to X - that is:

  - I
  - I I
  - I I I
  - I V
  - V
  - V I
  - V I I
  - V I I I (it is out of the range of 3 characters.)
  - I X
  - X

we have an I, V, and X at first position.  Then there is another I, X and V
   on the second position. After then again same I and V.  I have
   implemented this in the following regex of the above written code:

`\b(?!(IIX|IIV|IVV|IXX|IXI))I[IVX]{0,3}\b`

- Start it with I and then look for any of I, V, or X in a range of 'zero' to 'three' characters, and do neglect invalid numbers written inside the `?!(IIX|IIV|IVV|IXX|IXI)` Similarly, I have done with other combinations given below.
- Then for V and X : `\b(V|X)\b`
- Then for the VI, VII: `\bV[I]{1,2}\b`
- Then for the XI - XXX: `\b((?!XVV|XVX)X([IXV]{1,2}))\b`
- To validate a suffix name, i.e. `JR`, `SR`, one can use following regex: `\b[S|J]R\b`
- and the last (^$) is for matching a blank string or in other words, when no input has provided to the given `input-box` or `textbox`.

You may post any question or suggestion, if you have.

Thanks!

Ps: This regex is simply a solution to validate "roman numbers" from 1 to 30 using I, V, and X. I hope it helps to learn a bit to each and every newbie of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a more explicit:

```
(.+) (?:(?>JR$|SR$|I$|II$|III$|IV$|MD$|DO$|PHD$))|(.+)
```

I know I could do something like [JS]R but I like the way this reads:

`(.+)`  match any characters and then a space

`(?:(?>JR$|SR$|I$|II$|III$|IV$|MD$|DO$|PHD$))` atomically look for but don't match endings like JR etc

`|(.+)` if you don't find the endings then match any characters

Feel free to add the endings you'd like to suit your needs.